# Calling a C function from a Cobol program

Tags: c, cobol

We have a Shared library that has a function that is a web service client. The client was created with `gsoap` and this client is used by legacy progress 4GL applications to consume an encryption web service.

Now I have been asked if this same mechanism is possible with other legacy systems written in Cobol.

So, if I have this Shared library, can a function from this library be called by a Cobol program?

If possible, can anyone please share an example of reference documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a Micro Focus COBOL product, then looking at an C example, I would expect you do something alone the lines of:

1) do a h2cpy on "soapH.h" to get "soaph.cpy"
2) then....

```
    01 ws-soap  soap.

    call "soap_init" using
         by reference ws-soap
    end-call


    call "soap_call_ns1__...." using
         by reference ws-soap
         by value omitted   *> endpoint address
         by value omitted   *> soapAcition
        .... your parameters
    end-call

    if return-code not equals SOAP-OK
      call "soap_pint_fault" using
     else
        ...
    end-if

    call "soap_destroy" using
          by reference ws-soap
    end-call

    call "soap_end" using
          by reference ws-soap
    end-call

    call "soap_done" using
          by reference ws-soap
    end-call
```